# Typescript's CommonJS Internal Modules not recognized by NodeJS executor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I am creating a NodeJS application where I need to create internal modules to better organize my code logic and avoid having to write the full path when referencing such modules.

**internal-module.ts**

```
export class A {
    test() {
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of files with exported classes in them, which are then all exported from one index file.

**index.ts**

```
export * from './internal-module'
export * from './internal-module2'
```

I am then generating a single definition file for all of these internal modules by using `dts-generator`.

**index.d.ts**

```
declare module 'src/internal-module' {
     export class A {
     test(): void;
   }
}

declare module 'src/index' {
    export * from 'src/internal-module';
    export * from 'src/internal-module2';
}
```

Then I'm consuming such module as follows:

**consumer.ts**

```
import {A} from "src/internal-module";
```

This all works from a Typescript's perspective - as in, I get intellisense after I generate the definition files... but then when running the actual NodeJS code (after also compiling the `.ts` files), the modules are not being found:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'src/internal-module'
```

I noticed that in the compiled `.js` file there's this code:

**consumer.js**

```
var a = require("src/internal-module");
```

Seems like this is the same syntax that `NodeJS` uses for external modules, which searches through `node_modules` folder for. Am I missing something? Is the issue related to the way I'm compiling TS?

I'm compiling TS with the suggested `CommonJS` mode:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a relative path (prefixed by `./`):

```
import {A} from "./src/internal-module";
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid relative path for the simple reason that the consumer file might be changing directory and then I would have to also change the relative path.

Comment: @zalow517 Maybe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) can help you?